# Create a list from strings-list in Python

Tags: python

I have a list in Python:

```
['first', 'second', 'foo']
```

I want to create a list of lists named after the list elements:

```
newlist = ['first':[], 'second':[], 'foo':[]]
```

I have seen some proposals that use Dictionaries, but when I tried to do it with OrderedDict, I lost the order of the elements in the creation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: version 2.7.14.

Comment: If you want something (like `'first'`) to be associated with something (like a list), you have key-value-pairs. These are usually implemendet as `dict` (`{'first': [], 'second': []}`) but if you really want a list, then I recommend a list of `tuple`s (`[('first', []), ('second', [])]`).

Comment: *How* did you create the `OrderedDict`. It's sole purpose is to *retain* the order in which you insert the elements.

Comment: I declared : newlist= collections.OrderedDict() and later: used newlist= {i:[] for i in signal_list}. I get {'second':[], 'foo':[], 'first':[]} (i.e. different ordering)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the method `fromkeys()`:

```
l = ['first', 'second', 'foo']

dict.fromkeys(l, [])
# {'first': [], 'second': [], 'foo': []}
```

In Python 3.6 and below use `OrderedDict` instead of `dict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

l = ['first', 'second', 'foo']
OrderedDict.fromkeys(l, [])
# OrderedDict([('first', []), ('second', []), ('foo', [])])
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Python 3.7 regular Python's `dict`s are ordered:

```
>>> dict((name, []) for name in ['first', 'second', 'third'])
{'first': [], 'second': [], 'third': []}
```

`dict`s in CPython 3.6 are also ordered, but it's an implementation detail.

Comment: `{name: [] for name in ['first', 'second', 'third']}` would be a lot more natural.

Answer (score 1):

@ForceBru gave a nice answer for Python 3.7 (I learned myself), but for lower versions that would work:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
l = ['first', 'second', 'foo']
d = OrderedDict([(x, []) for x in l])
```

Comment: This one created [('first',[]), ('second',[]),('third',[])]. Not what I wanted

Comment: No, this one created `OrderedDict([('first', []), ('second', []), ('foo', [])])`. This is an OrderedDict object and not a list, don't confuse them.

Answer (score 1):

The elements in the array you wanna end up having must be proper objects and the format that you've displayed in the example, doesn't make a lot of sense, but you can try to use `dictionary` elements inside your array where each elemnt has key (e.i `'foo'`) and value (i.e `'[]'`). So you will end with something like this:

```
newlist = [{'first':[]}, {'second':[]}, {'foo':[]}]
```

Now if you are happy with that, here is a `map` function with an anonymous `lambda` function which is gonna convert your initial array:

```
simplelist = ['first', 'second', 'foo']
newlist = list(map(lambda item: {item:[]}, simplelist))
```

Hope, you got your answer.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The structure that you have indicated, is a dictionary `dict`. The structure looks like:

```
test_dictionary = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}

# To access an element
print(test_dictionary['a'])   # Prints 1
```

To create a dictionary, as per your requirement:

```
test_dictionary = dict((name, []) for name in ['first', 'second', 'foo'])
print(test_dictionary)
```

The above line of code gives the following output:

```
{'first': [], 'second': [], 'foo': []}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that you refer to the term "list", but you mean it as a word concept, not as a data type in Python language. The second problem is that the result will no longer represent the data type `<list>`, but the data type of the `<dict>` (dictionary). A simple one-line `for` can convert your variable-type `<list>` to the desired dictionary-type variable. It works in Python 2.7.x

```
>>> l = ['first', 'second', 'foo']
>>> type(l)
<type 'list'>
>>> d = {x:[] for x in l}
>>> type(d)
<type 'dict'>
>>> d
{'second': [], 'foo': [], 'first': []}
```